# How can I get the page url slug when 'post_name' returns an id?

Tags: customization, menus, urls, slug, id

I have the following code:

```
$menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
    $link = $menu_item->url;
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $slug = $menu_item->post_name;
}
```

The values of `$slug` yield page ids instead of the url slugs I'm looking for, except when the `$menu_item` is a Custom Link instead of a Page. What's more, the actual url has the slug I'm looking for, but `page_name` contains the same value as the page id.

Example:

```
echo $link;
>> 'http://localhost:8888/trips/'
echo $title;
>> 'Trips'
echo $slug;
>> 6195 // But I'm looking for 'trips'
```

I can hack the slug out of the `$link`, but I figure there has to be a more elegant way to achieve what I'm looking for.

Questions like [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11426/how-can-i-get-page-slug) and many others recommend grabbing `post_name`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
$menu = get_term( $locations[$theme_location], 'nav_menu' );
$menu_items = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id);

foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
    $link = $menu_item->url;
    $title = $menu_item->title;
    $slug = basename($menu_item->url);
}
```

Pass the whole permalink to the `basename` function, which will automatically process the URL and give us only the slug.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'd upvote you, but I'm super noob status.

Comment: I modified further, like so: `sanitize_title(basename($menu_item->url));`. This let me use the `$slug` as a class name for each menu list item... without worrying about potential garbage from a Custom Link.